# Compare pointers to C functions in Swift

Tags: c, swift, pointers, swift3

I'm looking for a way to compare pointers to c-functions. E.g.:

```
let firstHandler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler()

NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(onUncaughtException)
let secondHandler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler()

if firstHandler == secondHandler {
    debugPrint("equal")
}
```

Neighter `==`, nor `===` works

In Objective C I could express this as follows:

```
NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *firstHandler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler();

NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(onUncaughtException);
NSUncaughtExceptionHandler *secondHandler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler();

if (firstHandler == secondHandler) {
    NSLog(@"equal");
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you guys not have a .equals() method?

Comment: We have `==` operator to check for equality and `===` to compare pointers. However, things differ when working with `C`

Comment: C or Objective C? I don't see any C code here.

Comment: `NSUncaughtExceptionHandler` is a pointer to a `C` function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, you cannot compare functions for equality in Swift.
However, `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` returns a

```
(@convention(c) (NSException) -> Swift.Void)?
```

i.e. a (optional)  C-compatible function, and such a function can be
forcefully converted to an (optional) raw pointer with
`unsafeBitCast`:

```
let ptr1 = unsafeBitCast(firstHandler, to: Optional<UnsafeRawPointer>.self) 
let ptr2 = unsafeBitCast(secondHandler, to: Optional<UnsafeRawPointer>.self)
```

which can then be compared for equality

```
if ptr1 == ptr2 { .. }
```

---

A self-contained example:

```
func exceptionHandler1(exception : NSException) { }

func exceptionHandler2(exception : NSException) { }

NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler1)
let firstHandler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler()
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler2)
let secondHandler = NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler()

let ptr1 = unsafeBitCast(firstHandler, to: Optional<UnsafeRawPointer>.self) 
let ptr2 = unsafeBitCast(secondHandler, to: Optional<UnsafeRawPointer>.self) 

print(ptr1 == ptr2) // false
```

Comment: @hnh: It does compile and run without problems in my test. Did you apply it to a `@convention(c)` function?

Comment: Funky, works for me too now :-) I was testing with this: `let firstHandler  = Optional.some(Darwin.puts)`, but referring to `puts` actually doesn't result in a `@conv(c)`, weird.

Comment: @hnh: It seems that you have to annotate it explicitly: `Darwin.puts as (@convention(c) (UnsafePointer<Int8>!) -> Int32)`

Comment: can this be done with _operator overloading for `==`_

Comment: @nayem: Unless I am mistaken, you can overload == only for a concrete function signature, e.g. `func ==(lhs: (@convention(c) (NSException) -> Void)?, rhs: (@convention(c) (NSException) -> Void)?) -> Bool`, which is perhaps not very useful.

Comment: Great observation 

Comment: @MartinR, I found an another solution with `withUnsafePointer`. Please, take a look

Answer (score -6):

Based on your objective C example, what you want to compare is function's return values, not "pointers to functions".

Try this:

```
if (*firstHandler == *secondHandler) {
    NSLog(@"equal");
}
```

The "*" is going to dereference pointer so you can access the value stored at that location.

Comment: I need a way to compare those function pointers in `Swift`. I already know how to compare them in `Objective-C`